# Python 2.7: ValueError using csv to create a dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to read a 3 column csv into a dictionary with the code below. The 1st column is the unique identifier, and the following 2 are information related.

```
d = dict()
with open('filemane.csv', 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    mydict = dict((rows[0:3]) for rows in reader)


print mydict
```

When I run this code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "commissionsecurity.py", line 34, in <module>
    mydict = dict((rows[0:3]) for rows in reader)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
```

Comment: @shuttle87 thank you!  I'm new and learning.  I see now you declare the Key, and then the Values.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem then you can mark it as accepted with the green checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries need to get a key along with a value. When you have

```
mydict = dict((rows[0:3]) for rows in reader)
               ^^^^^^^^^
               ambiguous
```

You are passing in a list that is of length 3 which is not of the length 2 `(key, value)` format that is expected. The error message hints at this by saying that the length required is 2 and not the 3 that was provided. To fix this make the key be `rows[0]` and the associated value be `rows[1:3]`:

```
mydict = dict((rows[0], rows[1:3]) for rows in reader)
               ^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^
               key      value
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something along the lines of:

```
with open('filemane.csv', 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infield)
    d={row[0]:row[1:] for row in reader}
```

Or,

```
d=dict()
with open('filemane.csv', 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infield)
    for row in reader:
       d[row[0]]=row[1:]
```